# ng2-smart-table does not bind after delete

Tags: javascript, angular, ng2-smart-table

I am trying to use ng2-smart-table to show data and inline editing. However it seems something is wrong with this component. I cloned the repo and run some tests locally. I got the basic example demo and added the input data object to see the changes/binding in the object:

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="settings" [source]="data"></ng2-smart-table>
<pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
```

When I "Add New" row, it shows the new entry in the object array as expected. Editing any row works too, updating the row properly. However, when you delete a row, the object does not change and keeps showing the deleted row in the object array but not in the grid. When I try to add another row, it shows the new row in the grid, but it does not update/bind the new value in the object array. Update still works as expected.

I post this question in ng2-smart-table's github and I got not answer there so I hope I can get it here.

So it this a real bug? Here is the [**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/xr7fjXKRts7i7XKvf2a6?p=preview) with my tests.

Thank y'all.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not find any solution and I did not get any answer for the question I posted in github. So I abandoned the grid and start using regular grid :(

Comment: I tested this my angular 4 app and its working fine. I'll send working solution soon :)

Answer (score 4):

You have to refresh the local datasource which you handed to the table.

This is how I did it.

**HTML**

```
<ng2-smart-table 
    [settings]="itemTableSettings"
    [source]="itemSource" 
    (deleteConfirm)="onDeleteConfirm($event)">
</ng2-smart-table>
```

**Typescript Code**

```
import {LocalDataSource} from 'ng2-smart-table';

items: Item[];
itemSource: LocalDataSource;

itemTableSettings = {
    delete: {
      confirmDelete: true
    },
    columns: {...}
}

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.itemSource = new LocalDataSource(this.items);
}

onDeleteConfirm(event) {

    // Delete item from array
    let index = this.items.indexOf(event.data);
    console.log(index);
    this.items.splice(index, 1);

    // Update the array in the service class


    // Update the local datasource
    this.itemSource = new LocalDataSource(this.items);
}
```

Worked for me.

Comment: If you are fetching the array from a service class, you have to update that as well, then go for updating the datasource.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are a simpler solution:

```
 onDeleteConfirm(event): void {
    if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
      const index = event.source.data.indexOf(event.data);
      event.source.data.splice(index, 1);
      event.confirm.resolve();
    } else {
      event.confirm.reject();
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hi, your solution doesn't work well. After this delete action, add and edit actions are not working anymore. Priyabrata Pati's solution works fine even after deleting action.

Comment: I prefer your solution since yours are much simpler so I found way to fix it. I just add one line after the resolve() to refresh the data source: `this.data = [...this.data];`

Answer (score 0):

Added few lines of code to the plnkr code provided

Here is the working Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/UW9s11xhi5wJgt0nLzXj?p=preview

> In the template

```
<ng2-smart-table [settings]="tableSettings" [source]="data"
(deleteConfirm)="modifyData($event)"
(createConfirm)="addData($event)"
></ng2-smart-table>
    <pre>{{data | json}}</pre>
```

> In app.ts

```
delflag=false;
  addData(event){
    if(this.delflag){
      this.data.push(event.newData);
    }
    // console.log(event);
    event.confirm.resolve(event.newData);
  }
  modifyData(event){
    this.delflag=true;
    // console.log(this.data);
    let delrow=Object.keys(event.data);
    for(var j in this.data)
    {
      // console.log(this.data,event.data);
    if(this.data[j]==event.data)
      {
        this.data.splice(j,1);
        // this.data=event.source.data;
      }
    }
    event.confirm.resolve(event.source.data);

    // console.log(this.data)
    if(this.data.length==0)
      {this.data=[];
        this.delflag=false;
      }
  }
```

> In settings

```
tableSettings = {
add:{
     confirmCreate:true
    },
     delete :{
       confirmDelete: true
     },
//other fields
}
```

Hope this helps !!!

Answer (score 0):

Assome `data` is your table data source, so you have:

```js
onDeleteConfirm(event): void {
  if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
   this.data.remove(event.data)
  } else {

  }
}
```